# Target a div with no class or id inside a iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, overriding

Is it possible to add a class (or style) to a div inside an iframe?
The div has no class or id.

I'm trying to add a style (pointer-events:none) to the last div (the one with the transform-style:)

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="fnav">
    <div class="prev">
    </div>
    <div class="next">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widLoadingProgress loading-progress hidden">
    <div class="progress">
    </div>
    <div class="txtLoadingProgress caption">Please wait... the Application is Loading</div>
  </div>
  <div class="widLoading page-loading hidden">
  </div>
  <canvas width="2460" height="1846" style="width: 1230px;height: 923px;/* pointer-events: none; */"> </canvas>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;width: 1230px;height: 923px;position: absolute;top: 0px;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;perspective: 1722.34px;">
    <div style="transform-style: preserve-3d; width: 1230px; height: 923px; transform: translateZ(1722.34px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.02005e-06, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1.02005e-06, 0, -5.28334, -1.96462e-06, -30.7864, 1) translate(615px, 461.5px); display: block;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it a 3rd party iframe?

Comment: If the iframe content is from the same origin as the page/script that wants to set it yes it is. If not not.

Comment: It come from a wordpress plugin (this one: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/interactive-3d-flipbook-powered-physics-engine/)

Comment: Looks like cross origin after all, you're out of luck

Comment: it creates everything inside the same place... it's not charging from other web page